# How to change database queue connection in laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue

Im currently using laravel queue and works perfectly fine when I only have 1 database connection. But now that I need 2 database connection (one for local, one for production). How can I set the local as my connection for my database queue?

**What I tried**

*queue.php*

```
'database' => [
   'connection' => 'mysql_local',
   'driver' => 'database',
   'table' => 'jobs',
   'queue' => 'default',
   'retry_after' => 90,
   'after_commit' => false,
],
```

So I've added a `connection` key but queue still using my other connection.

*.env*

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=PRODUCTIONIP
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=core3
DB_USERNAME=adm
DB_PASSWORD=secret1234

DB_CONNECTION_LOCAL=mysql_local
DB_HOST_LOCAL=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_LOCAL=3306
DB_DATABASE_LOCAL=core3
DB_USERNAME_LOCAL=root
DB_PASSWORD_LOCAL=secret
```

I need to use the `mysql_local` connection, but no idea on how to use it.

Comment: Could you confirm that you've updated the `QUEUE_CONNECTION` env and also refreshed your config cache?

Comment: @AaronT Yes, it is already set to `database`, my only problem is switching between my local and production database used by `queue` in laravel. I can switch between these two though but I just cant switch it when Im using `queue`

Comment: Can you confirm that you've restarted your queue/workers when you switched?

Comment: Yes I did that as well